# Dynamic button names on jQuery dialogs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a webpage that uses different languages stored in localStorage, and on the jQuery dialog I want the names of the buttons to be dynamically changed according to the language, for example :

```
var btn_hello_text = getLanguageBtnHelloText();

$('#dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons: {
        btn_hello_text: function() { 
            doThings();
        }
    }
});
```

The problem here is that the dialog shows a button with the text `"btn_hello_text"` and not the value included in the variable itself. I can't figure a way to change the value of the button text dynamically, any hints? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [bracket notation](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/square_brackets.html) (instead of [dot notation](http://www.dev-archive.net/articles/js-dot-notation/)), like this:

```
var my_buttons = {};
my_buttons[getLanguageBtnHelloText()] = doThings;

$('#dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons: my_buttons 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that using inline object declaration. But it can be done by using the square bracket syntax instead:

```
var btn_hello_text = getLanguageBtnHelloText();

var buttonDefs = {};
buttonDefs[btn_hello_text] = function() { doThings(); };

$('#dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons: buttonDefs
});
```